# Windows XP won't http POST a large file

Tags: windows-xp, http

I've created a tool on our intranet where a user can send a (big) tgz file using a simple/basic html form (POST/multipart).

When using either firefox or IE:

- The form is not sent when the file is too large (2.44 Go)
- It succeeds when the file is smaller.
- It fails for the large file with for some other forms found on the web and having a "Select File..." input.
- (update) Sending the same big file on another computer works fine.

So, is there restriction parameter in XP fixing a maximum size for this kind of POST query ?

Many thanks,

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the limit isn't in the client, but is rather on the server.

For example, for IIS7 I usually use the following command to extend the limit to 100000000 bytes:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:100000000
```

The server must also be capable of handing such large files. An easy mistake is to keep the file in memory, thus exceeding the capabilities of a server with only 4GB of RAM.

Comment: It's a client problem. Sending the same file on another computer works fine.

Comment: @Pierre: If the browser is the same on both machines, there is no reason that it will malfunction on XP. XP itself has no mechanism for limiting socket traffic. It might be that a parameter of the browser limits the time that it is willing to wait, or that a badly parametered antivirus decided to intervene.

Comment: @Pierre: Idea - Is there a difference between the machines as regarding 32-bits / 64-bits ?

Comment: @harrymc thanks. The computer that failed is a 64 bits OS, the other machines are 32 bits.

Comment: @Pierre: Do you mean that it works on 32-bits and fails on 64-bits? I would have thought just the opposite.

Comment: Yes, i was surprised too.